# My Container/Sizebox containing column isnt taking full space of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 crousel images that can be viewed with a horizontal scroll and I have further text and details of them in texts below them which I want to be viewed but for some reason I keep getting bottomm overflowed by xyz pixels and  the column only occupies half the screen I want it to occupy full screen but I just doesnt work .

This is my code for home screen
and within it contains a wwidget that will call the crousel image section

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:park/utils/addressBox.dart';
import 'package:park/utils/constants.dart';
import 'package:park/utils/crouselImage.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'home_screen';
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).user;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(60),
          child: AppBar(
            flexibleSpace: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.lightBlue),
            ),
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'images/playstore.png',
                    width: 100,
                    height: 45,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 170),
                  child: const Text("Park it",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 30)),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: const [
            AddressBox(), //currently vechile reg number is being
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),

            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
            CrouselImage()
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Below is the crousel image code

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:park/utils/LocationDisplay.dart';
import 'package:park/utils/constants.dart';

class CrouselImage extends StatefulWidget {
  const CrouselImage({super.key});

  @override
  State<CrouselImage> createState() => _CrouselImageState();
}

class _CrouselImageState extends State<CrouselImage> {
  void performTask(int index, LocationDetail locationDetail) {
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) =>
            LocationDisplay(index: index, locationDetail: locationDetail),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselSlider(
        items: LocationDetail.locationDetails.map((locationDetail) {
          int index = LocationDetail.locationDetails.indexOf(locationDetail);
          return Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
// this is the container that contains all the stuff
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
//this is the column that contains the data and this column doesnt take up the full screen 
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children: [
                  Image.network(
                    locationDetail.imageURL,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 190,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    locationDetail.locationName,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    locationDetail.details,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    locationDetail.price,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => performTask(index, locationDetail),
                      child: const Text('Book'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          });
        }).toList(),
        options: CarouselOptions(viewportFraction: 1));
  }
}`
```

I have tied setting up height , expanded weapping it in row other columns nothing seems to work help me
The conatiner doesnt seem to increase in any height at all

[This image shows a parent column that contains a row at the top that is Addressbox().] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDaII.png)

This image is the crousel slider that is constrained within a space; for some reason, I want the slider and the text below to occupy the full screen. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zcr0F.png)

I want my crousel slider to take the full remaining white space at the botton too

Comment: can you include an image what exactly you are trying to get

Comment: try to wrap your `CarouselSlider` with expanded

Comment: tried that too doesn't work

Comment: you can follow my 1st comment and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)